# How Share an instance of Ignite between webapps?

Tags: ignite

I am trying to do a demo application, that reads some data and caches it to Ignite. This is a tomcat web application. I would like to start another tomcat web app on another machine, and would like to read data from the first webapp's ignite. Whatever config i use, looks like the second application is not able to find the first ignite instance?

I've tried using TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder and also TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder

Below is one of the config I tried

```
   <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                    <property name="multicastGroup" value="228.111.111.222"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Also tried below config

```
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
      <property name="addresses">
        <list>
            <!--local node -->
          <value>165.80.121.125</value>

            <!--Remote node -->
          <value>165.80.113.121</value>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

In both cases, i do not see the 2nd node connecting to the first node.
I also tried to start the first node as server, and the second as client, but still with no success. Can anyone suggest where am i going wrong?

Should i start a stand alone ignite client, and start ignite in client mode in both apps? Would that work?

Comment: Are you sure that relevant ports are open between hosts? Talking about 47100..47110, 47500..47510.

Comment: Hi, yes, the ports are open, below command produces some kind of output

cat < /dev/tcp/165.80.113.121/47100
ÿÿTö ÅFýºðõ

Comment: What about 47500?

Comment: Thats open as well

Comment: Then it should form a cluster, at least with VmFinder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should organize your application architecture to have separate server node(s) and Ignite clients. Client nodes could be embedded into your web application instances. In general client nodes doesn't store data, their purpose is to serve as a "facade" to server nodes.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.